# Please support [meta-tag:...] in comments on the main site

Tags: feature-request

Earlier today, I was trying to leave a comment asking a new user to open a [discussion](https://gardening.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/discussion) post here on [meta] for an edit to the [FAQ].  I noticed that using the `[meta-tag:discussion]` syntax for an automatically created link doesn't expand to a link to the meta page for that tag if it's in the comments on the main site.

I experimented a little and found that the `[tag:...]` syntax works on both the main site and on meta, but the `[meta-tag:...]` syntax only works on meta.  This discrepancy feels odd to me, so...

Please allow `[meta-tag:...]` in comments on the main site expand to the appropriate tag page on meta.